# Script doesn't find file

Tags: script, path

Suppose `my_folder` contains `my_script` and `my_program`. `my_script` tries to run `./my_program -myoptions`. It works when I `cd` into the directory, but not when I double click on it.

Here is the output:

```
CasebashMac:~ chris$ /Users/chris/Programs/synergy-1.3.1\ 2/work_comp_server ; exit;
/Users/chris/Programs/synergy-1.3.1 2/work_comp_server: line 1: ./synergys: No such file or directory
logout
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"./synergys" is a path relative to the directory which you are currently in. To fix this you will need to specify an absolute path, for example:

> /users/chris/Files/synergys

Obviously change it to a path that actually exists :)

Might be overkill, but there is a wikipedia page about paths:

[Path_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)

Comment: Why isn't the script run in the path it resides when I double click? Is there a way to refer to paths relative to the script?

Comment: Assuming you are using a bash script, this question over at stackoverflow will help you out :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-in